# How to write XPath query that contains HTML entities?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

I have this block of XML:

```
<bpmn:scriptTask id="UserTask_0qtrxsq" name="set variables app_from_user &amp; applist to &quot;ticketingsystem&quot;" scriptFormat="groovy">
... <bpmn:script> What should be matched is here ... </bpmn:script>
</bpmn:scriptTask>
```

in an XML file I'm trying to parse using Python and XPath. Below is the line that should match the script tag:

`getLines = xml.xpath('//*[local-name()="scriptTask"][@name="%s"]/*[local-name()="script"]/text()' % script_name)` where `script_name` should be `set variables app_from_user &amp; applist to &quot;ticketingsystem&quot;` in one of the iterations over all the existing scriptTask tags in the XML file.

It works fine for all other tags, but not for this one. When I removed the HTML entities (the placeholders for ampersands, quotes, etc. It worked fine:

```
<bpmn:scriptTask id="UserTask_0qtrxsq" name="set variables app_from_user" scriptFormat="groovy">
... <bpmn:script> What should be matched is here ... </bpmn:script>
</bpmn:scriptTask>
```

But I don't have control over the XML files and I want the script to be as generic as possible. Is there a way I could make the XPath query to extract what's inside the `script` tag without errors?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your quotes. In XPath, quotes have to be altered between `"` and `'`, respectively `&quot;` and `&apos;`, alternately. Because you use `&quot;` in your `%s` parameter, the surrounding brackets have to be `'` or, respectively, `&apos;`. So your XPath expression could look like this...

```
//*[local-name()='scriptTask'][@name='set variables app_from_user &amp; applist to &quot;ticketingsystem&quot;']/*[local-name()='script']/text()
```

and therefore your whole expression could look like the following:

```
getLines = xml.xpath("//*[local-name()='scriptTask'][@name='%s']/*[local-name()='script']/text()" % script_name)
```

Now the `&quot;` entities should be properly encapsulated in the `&apos;` entities of the `[@name='%s']`.

There is a reference about [entities in XML at W3Resource](https://www.w3resource.com/xml/prohibited-character-literals.php) which says:

> The apostrophe (') and quote characters (") may also need to be encoded as entities when used in attribute values. If the delimiter for the attribute value is the apostrophe, then the quote character is legal but the apostrophe character is not, because it would signal the end of the attribute value. If an apostrophe is needed, the character entity `&apos;` must be used. Similarly, if a quote character is needed in an attribute value that is delimited by quotes, then the character entity `&quot;` must be used.

Comment: This worked like a charm in most of the cases containing escaped HTML entities! However, there's still an issue... When I have an attribute with a value that contains a literal single quote, it fails. Any idea how I can circumvent that?

Comment: I have to disappoint you. I do not know of any way to achieve this. There is [this link at W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp) which explains the possibilities of an attribute. And there is [this link: "XML prohibited character literals"](https://www.w3resource.com/xml/prohibited-character-literals.php). Both say that certain XML entities cannot be contained in an attribute. So, sorry, I cannot help you in this regard. I guess that your task is indissoluble.

Comment: Just wanted to say I circumvented this by making it `@name=\"%s\"` and for `script_name` variable, I manually replaced double quotes to `&quot;` and magically, it worked for all cases!

Comment: Worth it to say that the original XML is inconsistent. Some `name` attribute values contain `&apos;` and some others contain literal single quote.